# Linear A morphology

Tags: morphology, greek

Linear A's lexicon is undeciphered, but I assume we know some things about it's morphology and phonology. I've only found
this theory that the language of Linear A had a lot of prefixes. Where can I find more information like this?

Answer (score 5):

Linear A was most probably used for a language different from Greek, usually it's called the Minoan language, it is an undeciphered and unclassified language.

You can use the bibliography Wikipedia always has at the end of its articles, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_A#Sources 
The paper by Owens, Gareth (1999), *The Structure of the Minoan Language* (PDF). Journal of Indo-European Studies. 27 (1–2): 15–56, in English, can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/110eOULv3c8JzK3xw0k5I1apiitSUtpg-/view?usp=sharing). 
Also see [Yves Duhoux, 1998, *Pre-Hellenic Language(s) of Crete*](https://www.academia.edu/26457474/Pre-Hellenic_Language_s_of_Crete).

Answer (score 1):

Linear A by David Packard (1974) is quite thorough if slightly dated, inc. sections for morphology and phonology https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vax3kwoscWQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false .

Another great resource is the one described in https://sigla.phis.me/paper.pdf and includes a searchable corpus of Linear A texts at https://sigla.phis.me/ .

Also when it comes to whole numbers Linear A (undeciphered) and Linear B (deciphered) share the same symbols (http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch14.pdf & https://www.jstor.org/stable/501989) so that's a small piece that is at least known.

Answer (score -2):

For your curiosity, I have just proposed a simple but effective method to translate linear A. I am currently working to find the divine symbols in these Minoan tablets:
https://nantt44.wordpress.com/2021/06/18/chapter-xiv-charmuthas-betius-charmuthas-and-linear-a-of-the-minoans/